# How do I remove overlapping faces for this case?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

[image]

Thanks for your attention!

I imported a svg image, extruded it, did the shortcut 'I' thingy.
Now I have those overlapping faces in corners.

I tried 'remove doubles' but it didn't remove any verticles(tried merge distance as well). Merge didn't do the job properly either.

How may I handle this? 
I want to extrude the inner face after organize the border part faces.

It would be lovely to have some advice long or short!
Thank you in advance. Wish you a lucky day :)

Comment: You could try extruding instead of inset on the top and bottom faces, so before inset select the top ngon, extrude and scale the resulting face a little bit down. Scale doesn't create overlaps like Inset so it might be enough to get clean rim. Geometry on top and bottom (Ngons) won't be nice but it might not be a problem at all (depends on the purpose of the mesh)

Comment: can you share the file

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to select the inner ring that you created with <kbd>I</kbd>. You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> for it. Then deselect everything that is fine with the circle selection tool (<kbd>C</kbd>). Then press <kbd>X</kbd> and select Edge Collapse. Your problems should now be fixed. For that selection part I made a little picture here:
[image]
Just deselect everything which is outside the problem area.

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge the faces at this point in your model.  Select two faces and them press Alt-M.  Select "To Center".

As answered before in the link below.
[Getting rid of theses overlapping edges to form a solid shape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141305/getting-rid-of-theses-overlapping-edges-to-form-a-solid-shape/141322#141322)