# Getting rid of theses overlapping edges to form a solid shape?

Tags: edges

[image: Overlapping Edges]

How would I go about cleaning this up and creating this into just one unified solid shape?

Comment: I have discovered I can use the Merge combined with a script to place a vertex point in between two edges. I've figured out the issue.

Comment: Sound great, could you please add an answer so others can benefit from your solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can select the vertices that you want to merge and press Alt-M.  Select to center.